# How to get a list of folder and file Google Drive API IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I want to get all file and folder name from my google drive using google drive API.

My query is like this:

```
 GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];

    query.q = @"";
     //or i also use this code

  query.q = @"mimeType = 'text/plain'";
```

Even I also tried this code:

```
-(void)getFileListFromSpecifiedParentFolder {
    GTLQueryDrive *query2 = [GTLQueryDrive queryForChildrenListWithFolderId:@"root"];
    query2.maxResults = 1000;

    // queryTicket can be used to track the status of the request.
    [self.driveService executeQuery:query2
                  completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                      GTLDriveChildList *children, NSError *error) {
                      NSLog(@"\nGoogle Drive: file count in the folder: %d", children.items.count);
                      //incase there is no files under this folder then we can avoid the fetching process
                      if (!children.items.count) {
                          return ;
                      }

                      if (error == nil) {
                          for (GTLDriveChildReference *child in children) {

                              GTLQuery *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesGetWithFileId:child.identifier];

                              // queryTicket can be used to track the status of the request.
                              [self.driveService executeQuery:query
                                            completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                                GTLDriveFile *file,
                                                                NSError *error) {

                                                NSLog(@"\nfile name = %@", file.originalFilename);
                                            }];
                          }
                      }
                  }];
}
```

Comment: [Here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list) you might find documentation (including Objective C code snippet) and a form to create request and check if you are using correct parameters

Comment: @A-live it's help full

Comment: feel free to answer it yourself or to provide more details.

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995787/listing-all-folder-content-from-google-drive/18009616#18009616)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)fetchGoogleDriveFileListWithfolderId:(NSString *)folderId
    :(void (^)(NSMutableArray *, NSError*))completionBlock
{
    GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
    query.q =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%@' in parents and trashed=false", folderId];

    GTLServiceTicket *ticketListing = [self.driveService
        executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,GTLDriveFileList *files, NSError *error)
    {
        NSMutableArray *mainArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        if (error == nil)
        {
            completionBlock(files.items,nill);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
            completionBlock(nil,error);
        }
    }];
}
```

Here  `query.q =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%@' in parents and trashed=false", folderId];`

folderId may "root"(For root folder),sharedWithMe (for shared folders)
.If you want to list trashed file then change trashed=true.

Comment: Just an update to @IOS's answer: `folderId` is `file.identifier`. If you want to get all files and folders then using "root" as `folderId`. Note: remember to use `kGTLAuthScopeDrive` instead of `kGTLAuthScopeDriveFile`.