# Only 82 kb 0f 3 MB is downloading from Google Drive?

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, google-api-objc-client

Hi I am downloading a media file of 3 MB from Google Drive. The file finish downloading after 82 kb.. it is not downloading completely. I have checked with small file.. but the download size remains constant for any size of file.. that is 82 kb..

I am trying GTMHTTPFetcher to download..but getting error

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
GTLDriveFile *file;
NSString *downloadedString = file.downloadUrl; // file is GTLDriveFile

NSLog(@"%@",file.downloadUrl);

GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher = [self.driveService.fetcherService  fetcherWithURLString:downloadedString];

[fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
    if (error == nil)
    {
        if(data != nil)
        {

            GTLDriveFile *file = [driveFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            filename=file.title;

            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            filename = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",fileNames]];
            NSData* Data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:targetURL];
            [Data writeToFile:filename atomically:YES];
            NSLog(@"my path:%@",filename);


        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error - %@", error.description);
    }
 }];


// from the above code error is **Domain=com.google.GTMHTTPFetcher Code=-1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.GTMHTTPFetcher error -1.)"**
```

Comment: What's the content of the file? Don't you use an authentification of some kind to access this file?

Comment: The content of file is audio, size is 3 MB..i already authenticated and listed files in table view..from there i m downloading..

Comment: is it failing ? did you check - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)aConn didFailWithError:(NSError *)error  ?

Comment: @zahreelay... i m not getting any kind of error....i have used this method

Comment: @LoïsDiQual ...i am trying to download 50 kb file than also it showing 80 kb what is the issue

Comment: @JamesRyan ...check -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection...method

Comment: @zahreelay...what is the issue....

Comment: I would look at the downloaded file in a dumb text editor or similar to see if its 82kB of audio data, or just some complicated link/text/error thing. Google Docs files 'download' as a url.

Comment: Can you please tell me how did you authenticate the access to file?

Comment: @TomAndersen What is the issue...why file is not downloading properly..even 1o kb file shows 82 kb...

Comment: @zahreelay issue is that file is downloading but when it is downloaded it shows 82 kb...all downloaded files are 82 kb ...if u can resolve..plz help

Comment: @zahreelay .are u there

Comment: @Wikiboo If i am able to list all files in table means they are authenticated...

Comment: don't use your own method, Google provided `GTMHTTPFetcher` to download the file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995787/listing-all-folder-content-from-google-drive/18009616#18009616

Comment: Can you check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002979/downloading-a-large-file-iphone-sdk

Comment: @JamesRyan, Yes I know, but how do you get direct link to download the file? From what I understand, the only way to download files from google drive is by using GTMHTTPFetcher.

webContentLink is not a direct link to file, neither is property downloadUrl, that is why you cannot download the file. I am also trying to solve this problem. I want to download the file by using its direct link and my own methods.

Comment: @Wikiboo how can i use this method.. i m trying but getting Domain=com.google.GTMHTTPFetcher Code=-1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.GTMHTTPFetcher error -1.)"

Comment: Please show the code where you are using GTMHTTPFetcher

Comment: @Wikiboo now check the modified code

Comment: @Wikiboo .. i m getting null value....

Comment: @TheTiger i m getting NULL value.... NSLog(@"%@",file.downloadUrl);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a solution, but I have a diagnosis, and the next step. If multiple files, some long, some short, are fetching 82KB, then double check that you are fetching the correct URL.

It looks like, when the user chooses a filename you aren't fetching the correct URL, but something returning 82KB of data, like the directory listing.

You can check by running the DrEdit sample app from https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/objectivec and by turning on GMHTTPFetcher logging, (GMHTTPFetcher is a wrapper for NSURLConnection) http://code.google.com/p/gtm-http-fetcher/wiki/GTMHTTPFetcherIntroduction#HTTP_Logging

Comment: Hi ... i have checked it.. but if u can elaborate ur answer how can i use the GTMFHTTPFetcher in Download Method it will be useful.. I hope u understand my issue.... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i think u r giving time out interval thats why its finishes loading at fix time.

Comment: plain English please. Or must I say "plz" for you?

Comment: I have changed various time interval.. from low to high but the file size remains constant that is 82 kb

Answer (score 0):

The method `downloadFormatSelected:` in the [DriveSample sample app][1] shows how to do an authenticated file download.

Comment: When i am Importing DriveSampleview file in my project i m getting error that cocoa file not found...if u explain how it can be possible it will be much better...thanks