# Google drive direct link to file

Tags: iphone, ios, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I know how to download the file from google drive:

```
GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth =
        [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName
                                                              clientID:kClientID
                                                          clientSecret:kClientSecret];
        [[self driveService] setAuthorizer:auth];

        GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher =
        [[self driveService].fetcherService fetcherWithURLString:song.filePath];
        [fetcher setReceivedDataBlock:^(NSData *dataReceivedSoFar) {
            [self.mutableData appendData:dataReceivedSoFar];

        }];

        [fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            if (error == nil) {
                // Handle downloaded file
            } else {
                NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);

            }
        }];
```

But is there a way to obtain direct link to file? Any way to authorize NSUrl to receive a direct link? I am trying to get it so I can stream audio files from google drive.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995787/listing-all-folder-content-from-google-drive/18009616#18009616

Comment: That answer uses GTMHTTPFetcher to download files, however, I am trying to get the direct link so I can stream from it, or download it by using my own methods

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `song.downloadUrl`.

```
GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher =
  [service.fetcherService fetcherWithURLString:file.downloadUrl];
```

Comment: I know that, I am trying to obtain a direct link to file, and not use GTMHTTPFetcher to download files. I need a direct link so I can stream audio file from google drive using AVPlayer

Comment: @Wikiboo if u plz tell me it is possible to stream google drive file without download plz let me know