# Doc file editing in iPhone app

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, openoffice.org

Would anyone please suggest me how can we edit word document in iphone/iPad application. I wont to open word document in my app and change font style and color and save it again. Is there any paid or free API or document for this which can help me for this.

I don't understand why you guys close this question. Look In below application on app store,
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/quickoffice-edit-office-documents/id578386521?mt=8
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/office2-hd/id364361728?mt=8

In above app he edit word document. I also tried below site for getting my point 
http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/rich-text-editing-sample-project/
http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/rich-text-editing-sample-project/
and many more but not getting exact idea how above application make document editable. So If you have any idea so please share.

Thanks.

Comment: @Kabira I tried this and others like http://csharpprogramming.blogspot.it/2010/12/export-datatable-to-excel.html